# SQLite Query For Dates Equals Today

Tags: sqlite, date, time

How to make the query to retrieve from database only the records that have the time equals to 'today'. I store my dates as long.

**E.g:**
DateColumn  (The name of my column) and the name of my table is MyTable

1360054701278 (Tuesday, February 5, 2013 8:58:21 AM GMT)
1359795295000 (Saturday, February 2, 2013 8:54:55 AM GMT)

So how should I make the query for this example in order to retrieve the first record (because it is the date equal to today)?

Any suggestion would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: `... WHERE date(yourdatetimecolumn) = date('now') ` does not work any more? edit: in your case convert your strange long (timestamp?) back to datetime

Comment: I've already tried it but I don't get nothing...

Comment: My time is in milliseconds. Why do you say it is strange? And how to convert back to datetime and why?

Comment: what is `SELECT DATE(datetime(yourcolumnname, 'unixepoch')) FROM yourtable` giving you?

Comment: If I make your above query I get this: -1413-03-01

Comment: yeah, thats due the fact you save milliseconds. SQLite internally can only save seconds since unix epoch, string dates or the days since somewhen around -4000 BC. Could you try the same with `SELECT DATE(datetime(yourcolumnname / 1000 , 'unixepoch')) FROM yourtable`

Comment: Yeeeeey, it's working :) Thank you very very much. I have used your last code into the first and it's working. This is the final query SELECT * FROM  MyTable WHERE date(datetime(DateColumn / 1000 , 'unixepoch')) = date('now')

Comment: Please post your answer to accept it :) Thanks again :D

Comment: Span-of-time comparisons are best done using the **"Half-Open"** approach where the beginning is inclusive and the ending exclusive. See [my answer on a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24593759/642706) for discussion and example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

sorry for not seeing that, your problem were the additional milliseconds saved in your column.

The solution was to remove them by division ;-)

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE date(datetime(DateColumn / 1000 , 'unixepoch')) = date('now')
```

Comment: Just one last question :): is it wrong to store the dates into database as milliseconds? Which is the best practice?

Answer (score 2):

Use a range for fastest query.  You want to avoid converting to compare.

```
SELECT *
FROM   My Table
WHERE  DateColumn BETWEEN JulianDay('now') AND JulianDay('now','+1 day','-0.001 second')
```

Note: I just realized your dates are not stored as Julian Dates which SQLite supports natively.  The concept is still the same, but you'll need to use your own conversion functions for whatever format you're storing your dates as.