# Check if timestamp (milli) belongs to a specific day

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, datetime

In a table of my SQLite database there is a timestamp (millisec) column. This table is really huge and I want a efficent way of querying all the rows that theire timestamp column refers to a specific day (in this case I want to get all enteries that belong to TODAY).

I came up with this, but it does not work and its quite slow. Any ideas will be appriciated. (NO I can not make any change in the database such as adding a DATETIME column...I have to do it with the timestamp).

```
public boolean isTimestampInToday(long timestamp){

    //get a timestamp from today
    long todayStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTimeInMillis(todayStamp);
    c.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    Date startDate = c.getTime(); //START OF DAY

    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);

    Date endDate = c.getTime(); //END OF DAY

    Long startStamp = startDate.getTime();
    Long endStamp = endDate.getTime();

    if(timestamp >= startStamp && timestamp < endStamp) {
        return true;            
    } else {
        return false;
    }      
}
```

I appriciate all the answers from expirienced guys, but to be honest the one that I could understand was the answer from @iaune. Now I have done this inside the query itself:

```
Calendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
gc.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
long toBeg = gc.getTimeInMillis();
toBeg -= toBeg % (24*60*60*1000);
long toEnd = toBeg + 24*60*60*1000;


Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(
        "SELECT * FROM "
                + DbHelper.TABLE_PA_DATA
                + " WHERE "
                + DbHelper.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP
                + " BETWEEN "
                + toBeg
                + " AND "
                + toEnd
        , null);
```

Is there anything wrong with this approach or can it be improved more?

**UPDATE**

I realised that using `INTEGER` for timestamp column type is wrong. I added a `DATETIME` column...I should now use direct SQLite query functions I guess. any ideas?

Here is what I get when I dump the table:

```
ID  DATETIME                    TIMESTAMP      STEPS    CALORIES
1   2014-07-06 07:18:55         169629539           3   0
2   2014-07-06 07:19:10         169644509           4   0
3   2014-07-06 08:15:36         173030229           1   0
4   2014-07-06 08:16:04         173058397           4   0
5   2014-07-06 08:31:39         173993598           2   0
6   2014-07-06 08:33:20         174094714           5   0
7   2014-07-06 09:31:54         177609142           1   0
8   2014-07-06 09:42:24         178238517           1   0
9   2014-07-06 10:37:37         181551849           1   0
10  2014-07-06 11:00:31         182925950           1   0
11  2014-07-06 12:17:42         187557035           1   0
12  2014-07-06 14:14:39         194573993           2   0
```

OK I managed to do it with some addition to @laune solution:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
// offset to add since we're not UTC
long offset = cal.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET) +
        cal.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET);
long toBeg = cal.getTimeInMillis();
toBeg -= (toBeg + offset) % (24*60*60*1000);
long toEnd = (toBeg) + 24*60*60*1000;
```

Using this query:

```
Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(
        "SELECT * FROM "
                + Database.TABLE_PA_DATA
                + " WHERE "
                + Database.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP
                + " BETWEEN "
                + toBeg
                + " AND "
                + toEnd, null
);
```

Comment: Where is your SQL code? Aren't you trying to query your database?

Comment: SQLite does not offer a Timestamp milliseconds-since-epoch data type. So what *exactly* is the [data type of your column](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)?

Comment: @BasilBourque its just an `integer` column

Comment: So are you storing seconds or milliseconds? Your question says milliseconds but the [SQLite doc](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) says seconds.

Comment: @BasilBourque I created the column `TIMESTAMP` as `INTEGER` and I store `System.currenttimemili` in it so I guess its millisecs

Comment: @BasilBourque I just realized that the TIMESTAMP column only has 9 digits...well ofcourse its integer :( I should have used a different type for this column

Comment: You make matters even more complicated by naming a column "timestamp" because "timestamp" is a specific data type [in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) and [in SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Date_and_time). Neither of those meanings is what you intend for that column. Assign meaningful names such as "when_item_sold_", "when_employee_hired_".

Comment: When you said your INTEGER-type column has only 9 digits, that makes no sense. I know next to nothing about SQLite, but the [doc for SQLite 3](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) defines an INTEGER-type column: `The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.` Understanding and mastering your database’s data types should be your first task before working on the programming. Probably it makes sense to use SQLite's facility to store a date-time value in the INTEGER column as a count of seconds-since-epoch in UTC.

Comment: @BasilBourque Yes you are right I found out that I used `getInt()` instead of `getLong()` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple arithmetic operations can avoid the costlier string and formatting operations. Not sure whether David meant what I propose, but maybe code expresses it more clearly:

```
Calendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
long toBeg = gc.getTimeInMillis();
toBeg -= toBeg % (24*60*60*1000);
long toEnd = toBeg + 24*60*60*1000;

long now = gc.getTimeInMillis();
if( toBeg <= now && now < toEnd ){
    System.out.println( "today" );
}
```

The values toBeg and toEnd, computed up front, can be used to run the query, according to the if. (To be precise, note the use of `<=` and `<`.)

Comment: This solution assumes you want "today" in GMT.

Comment: @DavidWallace Doesn't  `gc.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());` fix the problem?

Comment: @DavidWallace I suppose OP can use hiw own proposal or create the Calendar using GregorianCalendar(TimeZone zone).

Comment: @Sean87 No it doesn't.

Comment: If the timestamps aren't GMT s.o. has made a poor decision. What if this app is moved to another TZ? What if users running the APP come from a country with more than on TZ? What if the TZ changes in you locale (rare, I know, but...)?

Comment: @laune it's not a question of whether the timestamps are GMT - it's a question of whether the requirement is to have rows for "today" in GMT.  Where I live, such a requirement would make no sense - I'd end up EITHER getting data from yesterday afternoon plus this morning OR getting data from this afternoon plus tomorrow morning.  Most likely, if OP wants to report on "today's data", he/she means "today" in local time, not "today" in GMT.  And if that is the OP's requirement, then this solution will not work.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and [`new Date(long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29) like so,

```
// four digit year, two digit month, two digit day. For example, 20140706
private final DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
public boolean isTimestampInToday(final long timestamp){
  return sdf.format(new Date(timestamp)).equals(sdf.format(new Date()));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a `PreparedStatement` to select your data, with a `where` clause that includes

```
date_column between ? and ?
```

Once you've calculated the `startDate` and `endDate` - and the way you're doing it above is perfectly OK - set them to the parameters in the `PreparedStatement` and run it.

Answer (score 2):

## Half-Open

Date-time comparisons are better done with the "Half-Open" approach where the beginning of a span of time is inclusive and the ending is exclusive. For a single day that means you want query for date-times that are GREATER THAN OR EQUAL TO the first moment of the day in question AND LESS THAN the first moment of the day after. That is, up to bit not including the next day. This approach avoids the problem of infinitely splitting the last moment of the day.

## Joda-Time

The java,util.Date and .Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them. Use the Joda-Time library instead. It works in Android.

## Time Zone

Time zone is crucial. The definition of a day depends on the time zone.

Specify the desired time zone rather than rely on implicit default. Use [proper time zone names](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_tz_database_time_zones), not the 3 or 4 letter codes.

If you really want to use the JVM’s default time zone, I suggest explicitly calling `getDefault` rather than rely on implicit default. Such reliance often causes confusion in date-time work.

## Example Code

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.getDefault();  // Or DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Amsterdam" )
DateTime now = DateTime.now( timeZone );
DateTime todayStartOfDay = now.withTimeAtStartOfDay():
DateTime tomorrowStartOfDay = today.plusDays( 1 ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
```

From there you can call the [`getMillis`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/ReadableInstant.html#isBefore%28org.joda.time.ReadableInstant%29) to get a long which you can use to construct a java.sql.Timestamp object for your SQL query.

## SQL Logic

For Half-Open approach, we cannot use the SQL command `BETWEEN`. That command is inclusive on both comparators.

Instead, we need to write both our comparators, like this pseudo-code. Note `>=` versus `<` (no EQUALS SIGN).

```
SELECT * 
FROM some_table_ 
WHERE target >= todayStartOfDay.getMillis() 
AND target < tomorrowStartOfDay.getMillis();
```

Comment: I really couldn't understand your code either. I don't know how to link it to my SQL query. can you please check my updated question?

Comment: @Sean87 So you need a pair of numbers to represent each end of a span of time, each a count of seconds or milliseconds since [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)). The last sentence tells you how to extract such a number from a DateTime object in Joda-Time.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way

```
boolean isTimestampInToday(long timestamp) {
    Calendar c1 =  Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar c2 =  Calendar.getInstance();
    c2.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
    return c1.get(Calendar.DATE) == c2.get(Calendar.DATE);
}
```

Comment: I really couldn't understand this code. I don't know how to link it to my SQL query. can you please check my updated question?

Comment: But you said yourself ...I have to do it with the timestamp... so I propose a way to do this with the timestamp

Comment: Yes but I still can query the database and access timestamp coluimn, so I was wondering how to put your code to work in the query

Answer (score 1):

```
DateUtils.isToday(timeStampInMilli)
```

You can check if the timestamp is today's using this method.