# Android SQLite is it today

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-sql

This my Table codes

```
CREATE TABLE  InformationTable"
            + "(ID INTEGER, "
            + " ConfirmDate TEXT , "
            +" Counter INTEGER DEFAULT 99999"
            +" )";
```

I want to a select query about InformationTable. I want to create query like this ;

```
Select * from InformationTable where datetime(ConfirmDate) IS IT TODAY()
```

How can i do it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite Query For Dates Equals Today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14709661/sqlite-query-for-dates-equals-today)

Comment: It is not solved my problem sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your date is stored as `TEXT ISO8601` strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS"), to select the rows for today:

```
select * from InformationTable where date(ConfirmDate) == date('now');
```